# Arch Linux installation usb

Tags: linux, arch-linux, usb, uefi, iso

I burned the newest ISO to a flash drive using unetbootin, but it only comes up with this:

```
Arch Linux archiso x86_64 UEFI USB
UEFI Shell x86_64 v1
UEFI Shell x86_64 v2
EFI Default Loader
```

When I try to enter the UEFI thing it just boots into Arch cli with no option to install. How do I use my flash drive as a typical DVD installer medium to install Arch to my PC, rather than installing it to the flash drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you googled "arch linux install" yet?

The first link you should see, the Arch Linux Installation guide (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide), is what you are looking for.  The is also a much more explanatory beginner's guide (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide).

Unlike the Debian-installer, the menu-based thing that the Ubuntu installer is based off of, the Arch Linux installation process is entirely manual, so the command line is what you should see.

Have fun!  I feel like everybody needs to install Arch at least once, if nothing else so you know what the Debian installer does.

Comment: I meant to install unto another drive.

Comment: I know how to install all the components in the build from xorg to ldm. But none of the installation tutorials i have seen have covered how to do this. Please help me if you're able :)

Comment: You are referring to the re-formatting of the hard-drive (not the installation usb), followed by installing linux?  It is in the installation guide.  There's a whole guide for different partitioning techniques (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning), or I think the basic guide will walk you through using `parted`.  The actual installation step is after `chroot` in either guide.

Comment: I never understood that maybe because I first started learning about linux 4 months ago right now I'm a full time elementary user, but I'm looking for ultimate customizability. That bit of text you wrote made it all make sense to me. Thank You Rex :)

Comment: You're welcome.  You are starting the hard way, but the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with rexroni that installing Arch is an educational experience.  However, if you're in a rush and just want to get things done, you might look at Manjaro Linux (https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Download_Manjaro) which I think of as Arch with an installer.

Comment: I'll have a look at it.